# PY Как вытащить данные переменных из функции

Tags: python

Начал изучать питон, подскажите, что я делаю не так? У меня из функции не вытаскиваются значения, а вывод в консоли Visual Studio вообще вот так выглядит:
[Running] python -u "c:\Users\SNR93\Desktop\test.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\SNR93\Desktop\test.py", line 17, in 
print("� ���", cube_number, "��� � ������ �����", cube_edge,"�. ��� �����������", cube_line_edge, " ������ ����� �", cube_m_2, "�^2 ������")
NameError: name 'cube_line_edge' is not defined

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.05 seconds

```py
# глобальные переменные
cube_number = 2   #указываем количество кубов
cube_edge = 3     #указываем длину ребра в метрах


#делаем функцию
def cube_func(cube_number, cube_edge):
    global cube_m_2, cube_line_edge
    # считаем, сколько нам понадобится линий для кубов
    cube_lines = cube_number * 12
    # переводим палки в метры
    cube_line_edge = cube_lines * cube_edge
    # S = a^2 * 6
    cube_m_2 = (cube_edge**2 * 6) * cube_number
    return (cube_m_2, cube_line_edge)

print("У вас", cube_number, "куб с длиной ребра", cube_edge,"м. Вам понадобится", cube_line_edge, " метров палок и", cube_m_2, "м^2 стекла")
```

Comment: Так а вы функцию-то вызвали где-нибудь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот ваш пример, который будет работать:

```
# глобальные переменные
cube_number = 2   #указываем количество кубов
cube_edge = 3     #указываем длину ребра в метрах

#делаем функцию
def cube_func(cube_number, cube_edge):
    global cube_m_2, cube_line_edge# вот так делать не хорошо!
    # считаем, сколько нам понадобится линий для кубов
    cube_lines = cube_number * 12
    # переводим палки в метры
    cube_line_edge = cube_lines * cube_edge
    # S = a^2 * 6
    cube_m_2 = (cube_edge**2 * 6) * cube_number
    return (cube_m_2, cube_line_edge)

cube_func(cube_number, cube_edge)#нужно запустить функцию, чтобы глобальные
#переменные записались в памяти...

print(
    "У вас", cube_number, "куб с длиной ребра", cube_edge,"м. Вам понадобится",
     cube_line_edge, " метров палок и", cube_m_2, "м^2 стекла"
)
```

Вот так правильнее:

```
# глобальные переменные
cube_number = 2   #указываем количество кубов
cube_edge = 3     #указываем длину ребра в метрах

#делаем функцию
def cube_func(cube_number, cube_edge):

    # считаем, сколько нам понадобится линий для кубов
    cube_lines = cube_number * 12
    # переводим палки в метры
    cube_line_edge = cube_lines * cube_edge
    # S = a^2 * 6
    cube_m_2 = (cube_edge**2 * 6) * cube_number
    return (cube_m_2, cube_line_edge)

cube_m_2, cube_line_edge = cube_func(cube_number, cube_edge)
#получаем значения запуская функцию

print(
    "У вас", cube_number, "куб с длиной ребра",   cube_edge,"м.\nВам понадобится",
     cube_line_edge, " метров палок и", cube_m_2, "м^2 стекла"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы не вызвали функцию.

Обратите внимание, что параметры в функции могут иметь имена, отличные от имен переменных. Имеет значение лишь порядок их расположения.

```
par_1 = 17
par_2 = 24

def func(par_1, par_2):
    print(par_1, par_2)

func(par_2, par_1) #Выведет сначала 24, а потом 17
```

Также в функциях существуют позиционные параметры, которые имеют значения по умолчанию и в том случае, если функция будет требовать 3 значения, а при ее вызове будет передано лишь 2, то позиционный аргумент примет значение по умолчанию.

Важный момент: позиционные аргументы всегда стоят последними в функции.

```
par_1 = 17

def func(par_1, par_2 = 7): #У par_2 значение по умолчанию = 7
    print(par_1, par_2)

func(par_1) #Выведет сначала 17, а потом 7
```

Решение вашей проблемы ниже:

```
# глобальные переменные
cube_number = 2   #указываем количество кубов
cube_edge = 3     #указываем длину ребра в метрах


#делаем функцию
def cube_func(cube_number, cube_edge):
    global cube_m_2, cube_line_edge
    # считаем, сколько нам понадобится линий для кубов
    cube_lines = cube_number * 12
    # переводим палки в метры
    cube_line_edge = cube_lines * cube_edge
    # S = a^2 * 6
    cube_m_2 = (cube_edge**2 * 6) * cube_number
    return (cube_m_2, cube_line_edge)
print(cube_func(cube_number,cube_edge))
```

Comment: Глобальные переменные - "зло"

Comment: Этому парню пока не нужно об этом знать. Не все и не сразу. Придет с опытом.

Comment: Ну что вы такое говорите!!! Надо сразу к хорошему привыкать. С какой целью эти переменные объявлять глобальными? "зОчем?

Comment: Его пример вполне себе работает...  в гугл.колабе у него со шрифтами чего то не то

Comment: Просто по такой логике можно сразу с ассемблера начинать, для максимальной производительности)) Новичку на старте нужно стремиться только к полному изучению синтаксиса, а "фишечки" придут со временем. Имхо

Comment: Хотя странно, что я это говорю, ибо по-хорошему сам являюсь новичком, третий месяц на пайтоне только))